# Magento 2.3 same product with different custom options is not showing separate in the cart?

Tags: magento2.3, cart, addtocart, custom-options, shopping-cart

I am adding the same product in the cart with different custom options but the product is merging with the first one and item quantity increased in the cart only.

I want to show separate same products if they have different custom options. Increased quantity if they have same custom options.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Also having this issue. Doesn't seem to line up with other questions I've seen that have two of the same products in cart with different options (though they were configurable products).